# This code doesn't give me cos(x) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, trigonometry

I have modified the code of sin(x) from Otto's book to get cos(x) and I did the following:

```
v=0.:0.25:0.75;
cosx=zeros(size(v));
N=10; 
range=0:N;
ints=2*range;

for n=range 
   cosx=cosx + (-1)^n*v.^ints(n)/factorial(ints(n));
end
```

But the thing that this give 0 everywhere.

Can someone help me to fix this please? Thanks a lot

Comment: @user162343 - `cosx = 0;`, not `cosx=zeros(size(v));`.  You are calculating the Taylor Series approximation to `cos(x)`, and so you are incrementally adding terms of increasing order.

Comment: So can you post the correct code please ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change two things in the code to get the correct Taylor Series expansion. Here is the code. Notice the changes.

```
v=0:0.25:0.75;
cosx=zeros(1,size(v,2)); %Now, it's a vector
N=10; 
range=0:N;
ints=2*range;

for n=range 
   cosx=cosx + (-1)^n*v.^ints(n+1)/factorial(ints(n+1)); % replace n by n+1,        
                                                         % MATLAB indexing starts from 1.
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :), and another question, how can you do it with out converting zeros to a vector?

Comment: Parag, you should be able to save some calculation time by storing the value previous_value= `factorial(ints(n+1))` and instead of recalculating, just multiply `previous_value` by `ints(n+1)*(ints(n+1)-1)`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes. I just tried to make minimal modifications in his code.

Comment: @user162343 If you want `cos(v)` for each value in `v`, then you have to keep `cosx` as a vector of zeros. If you want to calculate only for a single value of `v`, then keep `cosx` as 0. Another option to avoid `v` as a vector (but not recommended), is to put another `for` loop on the values of `v`. Please accept the answer if I have solved your queries.

Comment: No I want a vector so your answer is what I was searching for tu thanks